# create data frame in R

Tags: r

see: [Selecting significant cases from a chi-squared test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753511/selecting-significant-cases-from-a-chi-squared-test)

The model example given in the case above is:

```
  f = function(N=1000){
   out <- data.frame("Row" = 1:N
                , "Column" = 1:N
               , "Chi.Square" = runif(N)
               ,  "df"= sample(N, 1:10, replace=T)
                ,  "p.value" = round(runif(N), 3)
               )
  return(out)
  }
```

but when I would apply this to my model I would turn this into:

```
 f = function(N=7000){
 combos <- combn(ncol(final),2)

 adply(combos, 2, function(x) {
 test <- chisq.test(final[, x[1]], final[, x[2]])

 out <- data.frame("Row" = colnames(final)[x[1]]
               , "Column" = colnames(final[x[2]])
               , "Chi.Square" = round(test$statistic,3)
               ,  "df"= test$parameter
               ,  "p.value" = round(test$p.value, 3)
                  )
return(out)
}}
```

yet R does not see this as a finished command line. Why?

Comment: So you're having trouble finding where to put the `)`? I'll bet if you try putting a `)` in a few random spots near the end, you'll figure it out.

Comment: @joran: that's terribly inefficient.  You need to write a genetic algorithm to add characters, and mutate and combine the lines until it produces the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a decent editor :-)

```
adply(
```

isn't closed.

Edit: nor

```
function(...){
```

It looks like the final `}` should really be a `)` + `}`

Comment: That's incorrect.  The final line should be `})}`.  Perhaps you need a better editor as well? ;-)

Comment: (it's more of a user problem...)