# Create a single output matrix using apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, apply, chi-squared

Dear programming gods,

I would like to perform a series of Chi-square tests in R (one test for each column of my species Presence/Absence data.frame) using a function that can yield a single matrix (or data.frame, ideally) which lists as output the species (column name), Chi-square test statistic, df, and p.value.

My species data snippet (actual dimensions = 50x131):

```
   Species<-structure(list(Acesac = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L
), Allpet = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Ambser = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Anoatt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Aritri = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L
)), .Names = c("Acesac", "Allpet", "Ambser", "Anoatt", "Aritri"
), row.names = c("BS1", "BS10", "BS2", "BS3", "BS4", "BS5", "BS6", 
"BS7", "BS8", "BS9", "LC1", "LC10", "LC2", "LC3", "LC4", "LC5", 
"LC6", "LC7", "LC8", "LC9", "TR1", "TR10", "TR2", "TR3", "TR4"
), class = "data.frame")

My environmental data snippet:
Env<-structure(list(Rock = structure(1:25, .Label = c("BS1", "BS10", 
"BS2", "BS3", "BS4", "BS5", "BS6", "BS7", "BS8", "BS9", "LC1", 
"LC10", "LC2", "LC3", "LC4", "LC5", "LC6", "LC7", "LC8", "LC9", 
"TR1", "TR10", "TR2", "TR3", "TR4", "TR5", "TR6", "TR7", "TR8", 
"TR9", "WD1", "WD10", "WD2", "WD3", "WD4", "WD5", "WD6", "WD7", 
"WD8", "WD9", "WW1", "WW10", "WW2", "WW3", "WW4", "WW5", "WW6", 
"WW7", "WW8", "WW9"), class = "factor"), Climbed = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("climbed", "unclimbed"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Rock", "Climbed"), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

The following apply function code performs a chi-sq test on each species (column) by first creating a contingency table with the number of occurrences of a given species on climbed vs. unclimbed rocks (Env$Climbed).

```
apply(Species, 2, function(x) {
  Table<-table(Env$Climbed, x)
  Test<-chisq.test(Table, corr = TRUE)
  out <- data.frame("Chi.Square" = round(Test$statistic,3)
                  , "df" = Test$parameter
                  , "p.value" = round(Test$p.value, 3)
  )
  })
```

This yields a separate data.frame for each species (column). I would like to yield one data.frame, which includes also the column name of each species. Something like this:

```
mydf<-data.frame("spp"= colnames(Species[1:25,]), "Chi.sq"=c(1:25), "df"=
  c(1:25),"p.value"= c(1:25))
```

Should this be done with ddply or adply? Or just a loop? (I tried, but failed). I reviewed a posting on a similar topic ([[Chi Square Analysis using for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382039/chi-square-analysis-using-for-loop-in-r][1])), but could not make it work for my purposes.

Thank you for your time and expertise!
TC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `apply` on `data.frames`. It internally coerces to a matrix, which can have unintended consequences for some data structures (i.e. factors). It is also not efficient (memorywise).

If you want to apply a function by column, use `lapply` (as a data.frame is a list)

You can use `plyr::ldply` do automagically return a `data.frame` not a list.

```
# rewrite the function so `Env$Climbed` is not hard coded....
my_fun <- function(x,y) {
  Table<-table(y, x)
  Test<-chisq.test(Table, corr = TRUE)
  out <- data.frame("Chi.Square" = round(Test$statistic,3)
                    , "df" = Test$parameter
                    , "p.value" = round(Test$p.value, 3)
  )

}
library(plyr)
results <- ldply(Species,my_fun, y = Env$Climbed)
results
# .id Chi.Square df p.value
# 1 Acesac      0.000  1   1.000
# 2 Allpet      0.000  1   1.000
# 3 Ambser      0.000  1   1.000
# 4 Anoatt      0.338  1   0.561
# 5 Aritri      0.085  1   0.770
```

Comment: Mnel, would you be able to offer code for how to add to this output a Holm's corrected p-value for each chi-square test?

Comment: @user3729247 -- that is a separate (statistical) question. You should ask a well formed question on `stats.stackexchange` (if you can't find an similar question there)

Answer (score 1):

If you save the result of your `apply` as

```
kk <- apply(Species, 2, function(x) {...})
```

Then you can finish the transformation with

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x,y) cbind(x, species=y), kk, names(kk)))
```

Here we just append the name of the species to each data.frame and combine all the rows with `rbind`.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. I'm not a fan of using two datasets and hoping they are in the same order though. Merging first like `intm <- merge(Species,Env,by.x="row.names",by.y="Rock")` would probably be wise.

Comment: Don't encourage people to use `apply` on data.frames! This will coerce internally to a matrix and thus not be efficient. Promote better coding practice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
kk <- apply(Species,2,....) 
library(plyr)
ldply(kk,.id='spp') 
 spp Chi.Square df p.value
1 Acesac      0.000  1   1.000
2 Allpet      0.000  1   1.000
3 Ambser      0.000  1   1.000
4 Anoatt      0.338  1   0.561
5 Aritri      0.085  1   0.770
```

Upd:

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
ddply(setNames(melt(Species), c("spp", "value")), .(spp), function(x) {
Test <- chisq.test(table(Env$Climbed, x$value), corr = TRUE)
data.frame(Chi.Square = round(Test$statistic, 3), df = Test$parameter, p.value = round(Test$p.value, 
    3))
```

})